# Get button click value for saving into SQL Server table

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons which allow a user to click on one to do some calculation. I need to get the button that is clicked value and store it in a SQL Server table.

I am trying to do as below but it's not working:

```js
  vSubstract: $("input[name='vSubstract']:click").val();
```

```html
 <input id="vSubstract" name="vSubstract" type="button" value="-">       
 <input id="vplus" name="vplus" type="button" value="+">
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, then you are doing it wrong way, You can do something like below:

```
$('input[name="vSubstract"]').on('click', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
});
```